# Как отправить данные заказа Woocoomerce через api?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

подскажите пожалуйста какая функция отвечает за отправку заказа на почту. А точнее каким образом отловить данное события и отправить через CUstom APi данные в CRM насчет заказа? CRM самописная и не имеет плагина для подключения - поэтому вывод подключение через API

Comment: Посмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/30653178/1278262

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хук `woocommerce_resume_order` там даже описание, для 3-d API's.

```
function my_awesome_crm( $order_id ) {
    // You code here
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_resume_order', 'my_awesome_crm' );
```

Comment: Спасибо, подскажите пожалуйста для отладки функции , к примеру var_dump($order_id) - где можно посмотреть?